# Finding average for a single day

Tags: c#

I am setting up a database to save blood pressure values.

I use `ListView` to store my datas and timedatepicker to select my dates

Trying to find an average Value per day. Currently not too sure how to go about it .

The user will be able to input their own values and save it under mornings, afternoons, evenings and nights for each date.

How can I make it so that the program can find all data given by the timedatepicker for that particular dat and find an average?

using XML file to save data.

I have only been able to find the total average of all data as follows:

```
foreach (BloodpressureData objekt in BloodpressureListe)
{
    Totalsys += objekt.Sys;
    Totaldia += objekt.Dia;
    Totalpuls += objekt.Puls;
    count += 1;
}

if (Calculate == true)
{
    if (count != 0)
    {
        Totalaveragesys = Totalsys / count;
        Totalaveragedia = Totaldia / count;
        TotalaveragePuls = Totalpuls / count;

        lbltotalavSys.Text = Totalaveragesys.ToString();
        lbltotalavdiawert.Text = Totalaveragedia.ToString();
        lbltotalavPulswert.Text =TotalaveragePuls.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to provide more details of e.g. the definition of `BloodpressureData`. YOu can use LINQ `Where` to filter.

Comment: If there are more than one BP reads per day, `BloodpressureData` needs to have a date element in it (otherwise your foreach is already iterating days).  Then decide if you are iterating the collection or days ion a week/month to do the averaging.  A BO Collection object works great to calculate the actual avg BP

Comment: The calculation should probably be done in the database. How are you communicating with the db, and we can go from there to get the right result.

Comment: ...in addition to the date your `BloodpressureData` class ought to have an enum or something to indicate the time of day so certain 'rules' can be applied.  For example, a "wake up" reading may be wanted but not included in the average (because they can be v high from the adrenaline produced to wake up), also if the patient exercises a reading directly after can be 15-20 ticks low.  Those can distort the average so they are often excluded...a BP collection is great for such rules (and options)